# What does `Oriented` mean in object-oriented,or connection-oriented?

Tags: oop

Like the title,there are also `Aspect-oriented`,`Procedure-oriented`.

I know that `Object-oriented` is something about `encapsulation`,`inheritance`,`polymorphism`, but I think I still didn't get the point,and what exactly does `oriented` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"oriented" comes from the word "orientation", which in turn comes from the word "orient", which means "East".  In ancient times a traveler needed to "orient" thenmselves so as to know which way is East, so as to know which way to go.   Then later the compass was invented, so the North started being more important than the East.

So, figuratively speaking, when you are "oriented" towards A it means that you are traveling in the general direction of A.  And even more figuratively speaking, when you are "oriented" towards A it means that you keep constantly having A in mind, and striving towards A.

The word is generally used when we want to imply a loose relationship instead of a hard doctrine.

Comment: Good explanation~! And thanks for the story letting me know why "orient" has a meaning--"east" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would say here by oriented we tend to say the way this thing is going to work or you can say what this thing is going to focus on.

In Object oriented programming, you are going to work with objects or the programming language will focus more on objects. Similarly for aspect oriented you are going to work with aspects and in procedure oriented you are going to work with procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about others but in `Object-oriented` it means working around the object or working with object(s) where every logical or conceptual entity is depicted as real world object.

FYI, in OOP there are two terms `Object Based` and `Object Oriented` and the only difference is that `Object Based` programming languages doesn't support `Inheritance` whereas `Object Oriented` indeed does.